# how to disable xPage placeBar button?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I have placebar button defined like this:

```
<xc:ccMain>
    <xc:this.placeBarActions>
        <xe:basicLeafNode label="Save" onClick="XSP.executeOnServer('#{id:saveEventHandler}','#{id:applicationLayout1}')">
        </xe:basicLeafNode>
        ..........
```

and then:

```
    <xp:eventHandler id="saveEventHandler" submit="true" event="calledbyid" refreshMode="complete" action="#{javascript:saveDocument();}"></xp:eventHandler>
```

I want to disable that "Save" button onClick event especially by Client Side JS

Thank you

Comment: I'm having a hard time to get what you mean: you want the button to be disabled as soon as someone clicks on it? If so: needs it to be disabled from theon on, for everyone else, or just for the person who clicked it, and only until the page is reloaded? Why do you need to do this through csjs?

Comment: 1. Yes, as soon as someone clicks on it. 2. Just for person who clicks it. 3. Only until the page is reloaded. 4. I do need to disable it immediately so users can't click it second time. This is why I thought CSJS would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to disable button "Save" during document's saving and page reloading.

Your basicLeafNode is a child of placeBarActions.
It gets rendered to

```html
<span class="lotusBtn">
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:...">Save</a>
</span>
```

Unfortunately, there is no property "disabled" for a href tag for easy button disabling.

Overwrite button's `onclick` event with `'return false;'` instead. It does nothing when user clicks button a second time during execution.

Set color to gray to make it visible that button is disabled during execution. You have to set it with `color:gray !important` because OneUI's definition for `.lotusBtn a` is `color: #000 !important` which would overrule the gray setting otherwise.

Change your code this way

```xml
<xe:basicLeafNode
    label="Save"
    onClick="event.target.onclick= 'return false;';
             event.target.setAttribute('style', 'color:gray !important');
             XSP.executeOnServer('#{id:saveEventHandler}', '#{id:applicationLayout1}');">
</xe:basicLeafNode>
```

As this basicLeafNode is part of applicationLayout1 it gets restored to it's original content after page is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using CSJS which in my opinion makes this task unnecessarily complicated I would use a combination of SSJS and partial refresh:

1. the server side `onclick` event sets a `viewScope` variable (`requestScope` may not be sufficient) like

   `viewScope("isDisabled", true)`
2. the same event performs a partial refresh on a named `xp:div` or `xp:panel` surrounding the button, or maybe even only the named `xp:button` itself
3. the button's disabled property evaluates your `viewScope` variable programmatically:

   `disabled="#{javascript:viewScope("isDisabled")}"`

Should do the trick.